# Can I count number of new JUnit tests per person using git log?

Tags: git

Is there any way for me to find who has committed the most number of lines containing `@Test` using `git log` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this short python script which looks for a similar pattern in a python codebase:

```
import collections
import subprocess


lines_by_author = collections.defaultdict(int)


for line in subprocess.check_output((
    'git', 'log', '-G', '^def test', '--format=%ae %h',
)).decode().splitlines():
    email, h = line.split()
    for line in subprocess.check_output((
        'git', 'show', h,
    )).decode().splitlines():
        if line.startswith('+def test'):
            lines_by_author[email] += 1
        elif line.startswith('-def test'):
            lines_by_author[email] += 1

import pprint
pprint.pprint(sorted(lines_by_author.items(), key=lambda kv: -1 * kv[1]))
```

The script can be modified to look for `@Test` by changing the parameter to `-G` and the two `startswith()` calls.

It will produce output like:

```
$ python3 tests_by_user.py
[('user1@example.com', 1351),
 ('user2@example.com', 129),
 ('user3@example.com', -5)]
```